# How to scrape specific name from link bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use bs4 to scrape this webpage to get the titles of  the "Episode" and the rating. I already have the rating down and I'm using the following code

```
first_url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?series=tt0206512&view=simple&sort=release_date,asc'

page = requests.get(first_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# get a list of descriptions to parse
ratings = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "col-imdb-rating"})
```

However, when I try to use the tag 'a', it's not quite working. Does anyone have suggestions on how to get each episode name from this [website](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?series=tt0206512&sort=release_date,asc&view=advanced)?

So I'm looking for here: "Help Wanted/Reef Blower/Tea at the Treedome"

[image: html for page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many `a` elements on the website, therefore all episodes can be obtained by using the closest element (in this case small) to retrieve element a which contains the episode. The closest element to small can be represented by a `+` sign. Try this

```
episodes = soup.select("div.lister-item small + a[href]")
for episode in episodes:
  print(episode.text)
```

Comment: That's super cool! I want to look more into the adding a "+" sign. Where would you recommend learning about this if you have a specific resource?

Comment: Thanks! Just take a look at `Combinators` : [source 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators) & [source 2](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When a URL is given as `/some/folder/somepage`, it's with respect to the root page (`https://www.imdb.com` in this case). So [get the `href` value from `<a>` tag](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) and append it, to get `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0707293/?ref_=adv_li_tt`.